# Do you prefix your classnames?

Tags: php, coding-style

Simple question : do you prefix your PHP classes (for example your library classes) with the name of your company ?

Example : Zend prefix everything with "Zend_", but that's normal because this is a framework (so they want to avoid conflicts).
Should I do the same for the library classes of my company ? Will I ever get conflicts ?

I think this is easier to use without the prefix (shorter names), but is that a good practice to have a prefix ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

PHP has **[namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php)**. You should use them instead of prefixing everything with a name.

At the very least, your developers will thank you when they don't have to keep typing `MyFrameworkName...` just to start using one of your classes.

Comment: Prefixing classes is not a part of Hungarian notation.

Comment: Improper hungarian notation should be avoided. True hungarian, however, can be very helpful, especially in a language like PHP.

Answer (score 3):

I always prefix my classes for a number of reasons

- 5.2 will still be around for a couple of years
- 5.3 namespaces are totally ugly, i cannot use them without getting nauseous
- and hey, apple does that too (NSString, CFXMLParser etc) ;))

Seriously, it's better to avoid explicit class names altogether. Get rid of statics and use dependency injection instead of `new` - and you'll have much less pain with class naming.

Comment: 5.2 is not a problem, there is no practical constraint, just a theorical question.

Answer (score 1):

No.

PHP has namespacing, so you can have classes with the same name so long as they’re in different namespaces.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I do. I can't switch to namespaces b/c most of my clients are running PHP 5.3 yet. I don't mind typing a little more if I'm guaranteed to avoid naming conflicts. Especially when I'm using my own custom library on top of existing ones.

Answer (score 0):

i prefix my classnames with the folder name it lives is in

```
<?php
    // filename would be "ClassName.php" in directory "directory"
    class directory_ClassName{

    }
```

that way it make using __autoLoad extremely easy

```
function __autoload( $class_name ){
    $file = explode( "_", $class_name );
    $file =  'app/' . implode( '/', $file ) . ".php";
    require_once( $file );
}
```

meaning you never have to load your classes, its all done automagicly

Comment: I used to do this, then I started dumping everything into a single directory... if I'm under 100 classes. Nothing angers me more than typing "cd" :)